# Mi programa no funciona

Tags: c

En el momento de ejecutar mi programa funciona, pero en trapecio y en rectángulo este se traba. Lo he comprobado y no se cual es el fallo.

Este es el código.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>
main()
{

***case 5: printf("Area trapecio\n");
float Atrap, Bmayor, Bmenor, htrap; 
printf("introducir Bmayor\n");   
scanf("%f",&Bmayor); 
printf("introducir Bmenor\n");   
scanf("%f",&Bmenor); 
printf("introducir htrap\n");   
scanf("%f",htrap); Atrap=htrap*((Bmayor+Bmenor)/2);   
printf("Area del trapecio es=%f\n",Atrap);
      break;

    case 6:
        printf("Area del rectangulo\n");
        int Base,Altura,Arecta;
        printf("Introducir Base\n");
        scanf("%d",&Base);
        printf("Introdcir Altura\n");
        scanf("%d",Altura);
        Arecta= Base*Altura;
        printf("Area del rectangulo es=%d\n",Arecta);
        break;***


      }

getch();
return(0);
}
```

Comment: trata de inicializar las variables

Comment: Tu problema puede estar en la declaracion de las variables o lo que estes usando para los cases, lo mejor seria que pongas el codigo completo para poder revisar. De todas maneras, ayuda saber que compilador usas y que error te esta diciendo.

Comment: Mismo error en ambos, mira las lineas `scanf("%d",Altura)` y `scanf("%f", htrap)`... Dado que solo te pasa en estos dos casos supongo que son dos errores tipográficos... Te falta el operador de referencia (`&`) : `scanf("%d",&Altura)` y `scanf("%f", &htrap)`. Tres apuntes, **1:**  Esto es C y no C++ como te han comentado (usa las etiquetas correctas). **2:** Formatea tu código para que se vea como tal: lo seleccionas y pulsas `Ctrl` + `K` o el boton `{}` del editor. **3:** No agregues  información adiciona en respuestas nunca, edita tu pregunta usando el botón `editar` de debajo de esta.

Comment: Lo que no jala es tu pregunta, edítala por favor X_X

Comment: Zoeck , para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida revisa [ask].

Comment: Aceptaría que le programa fuese C++ si tuviese una sola referencia a dicho lenguaje... pero esto es código C. Para próximas referencias, por favor, haz preguntas serias y bien documentadas

Comment: si lo siento a todos la verdad ya vi ese error la verdad

Comment: espero en que despues suba prgroamas con errores menos "tontos"

Answer (score 2):

```
scanf("%f",&Bmenor); 
//         ^ -> correcto

scanf("%f", htrap);
//         ^ -> error
```

El programa falla simplemente porque `scanf` espera recibir un puntero (es decir, una dirección de memoria) y tu le estás pasando una variable *a lo bruto*.

```
scanf("%f",&htrap);
```